# Spring 3.0 MVC error: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I referred to sample spring application on netbeans.org and tried to create a simple login application. When I run I get this error:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute`

Here is my login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Business SMS Login</title>            
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <spring:nestedPath path="login">
        <form name="frmBSMSLogin" action="" method="post">
        <div id="controls">
            <div id="lgnUsername">
                <label for="txtUsername">Username</label>                     
                <spring:bind path="login.username">
                    <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" id="txtUsername" maxlength="20" class="textInput"/>
                </spring:bind>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="lgnPassword">
                <label for="txtPassword">Password:</label>
                <spring:bind path="login.password">
                    <input type="password" id="txtPassword" maxlength="20" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" class="textInput"/>
                </spring:bind>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submitSection">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" class="buttonInput"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="buttonInput"/>
        </div>
        </form>
        </spring:nestedPath>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the LoginController.java

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import java.net.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;   
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import service.Login;

public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController {
private Login login;
public LoginController() {
    setCommandClass(GetLoginDetails.class);
    setCommandName("login");
    setSuccessView("dashboard");
    setFormView("index");
}

public void setLogin(Login login){
    this.login = login;
}

protected ModelAndView onSubmit( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)throws Exception {           
    //System.out.println("are we here?");
    GetLoginDetails l = (GetLoginDetails) command;
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
    mv.addObject("helloMessage", login.authenticate(l.getUsername(),l.getPassword()));
    return mv;
}
```

}

This is the applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean name="login" class="service.Login"/>

</beans>
```

I have been on this thing since last entire week I think. I am doing this by referring to netbeans' example. Here's the link http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html. I haven't found any solution to this. Begin from PHP background I am already finding spring framework too damn difficult, however I am trying with full efforts. I am using Netbeans as my IDE. Is it a good choice or Eclipse is the standard one? Also please give me some advice on how to debug the application. simple echo  or print_r as in php looks too much of a luxury here :)

P.s I had posted similar question before, and someone from around here had complained of it being a code dump and downvoted me. There are many question where there is a huge code dump yet people were kind enough to help. So anyone who thinks this a code dump or somewhat in rude language please don't waste your precious time downvoting this question. I am a genuine learner here to ask for help

Comment: in spring 3.0 why you are using SimpleFormController? why not try the annotation way of doing the controller using `@Controller`?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But as I have mentioned in my problem, I have just begun with spring. I just followed a tutorial. I don't know an iota by what you're saying about annotation..sorry :|

Comment: yes, I had seen a totally different approach for spring in couple other examples. But since I had netbeans and tutorial was designed for it, I went with it. I went to spring's own website and tried a sample app there. It was so goddamned difficult and all the mess of xml for even ant script, it was almost repulsive. Sometimes I think things like spring will never be my cup of tea after doing kiddie's stuff like php :D

Comment: here is a simple sample of hello world using annotations in spring http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/. nothing is impossible if we practice :-). enjoy!!!

Comment: thanks for that one. I had tried the hello world example. But this one is where I came across form submit and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove

```
<spring:nestedPath path="login">
```

after

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
```

spring:nestedPath - Sets a nested path to be used by the bind tag's path.

UPD:

Read about this tag [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/NestedPathTag.html)

Comment: i tried but it didn't work gave me the same error. I jst removed nested path tags. but spring bind tag is still there. I think they have to be there so that service can access the form fields right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. In your case you can remove spring:nestedPath OR do not use "login." in spring:bind (for example you need to write <spring:bind path="password">)

Answer (score 1):

had same error using spring's form tag.
resolved by adding modelAttribute:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="hall" method="post" action="saveChanges">
```

hope this would help somehow